# Unzip all file without it's folder using Java

Tags: command-line, java, zip, rar

Is it possible to unzip all files from the zip folder without its folder?

**Example:**

zipfolder.zip has two subfolders called folder1(having files like 1.txt, 2.xlsx, 3.pdf) and folder2(having files like 4.txt, 5.pdf)

**Note:** *The source can any type of archive files like .zip, .rar, .tar, .7-zip etc*

**This is my code:**

```
String sevenZipLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe";
String src = source filepath (zip file)
String target = output path (output path)

String[] command={sevenZipLocation,"x",src,"-o"+target,"-aou","-y"};

ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder( command );
Process process = p.start();

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("line1 "+line);
}
process.waitFor();
```

When I execute this code the output like

unzip folder ----- folder1(having files like 1.txt, 2.xlsx, 3.pdf) and folder2(having files like 4.txt, 5.pdf)

But I want to extract the only file from all folders and the output like 
1.txt, 2.xlsx, 3.pdf, 4.txt, 5.pdf in the output path.

Is there any command for that. Thanks.

Comment: Run "7z --help" and see if it has the "e" command "extract without directory".

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/960/java-unzip-file-example

Comment: These will help you. You do not need to run CMD commands.

Comment: The above link can extract only zip file, not the .rar, .tar, .7-Zip files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to change:

```
String[] command={sevenZipLocation,"e",src,"-o"+target,"-aou","-y","*.*","-r"};
```

PS. I don't think Java is the best choice to run OS commands.  You'll be wasting a lot of time.  But if you insist, don't forget there might be an errorstream too.

Comment: Above answer also extract with the subfolders, How to eliminate the folder creation.

Comment: It's Working. Thank you